# Repeat details section in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm new in Crystal Reports. I'm trying to create a report with some tables of my database. So, I created a DataSet with that tables and i joined tables. I have:

```
A (primary table; key field id_a)
B (join to A by id_a; one to one relationship)
C (join to A by id_a; one to many relationship)
D (join to C by id_c; one to many relationship)
```

Then I try to create this form in the design view:

```
Name column X: value of A.column_x
Name column Y: value of A.column_y
Name column Z: value of B.column_z

Name column D.column_j      Name column D.column_i
XYJ                          HJU
IOP                          IOP
```

There are one record in table A (I filter by a parameter) and multiple line items value in table D for this value in A. I view in the output:

```
Name column X: value of A.column_x
Name column Y: value of A.column_y
Name column Z: value of B.column_z 

Name column D.column_j      Name column D.column_i
XYJ                          HJU


Name column X: value of A.column_x
Name column Y: value of A.column_y
Name column Z: value of B.column_z 

Name column D.column_j      Name column D.column_i
IOP                          IOP
```

I don't know why, but the first part is repeated again and again every time that D columns values are shown and besides I don't know how to put values of D all together.

I tried to fix it by creating a view of tables C and D but it's the same. I have separated both parts in different details section but nothing changes.

EDIT:

As i told, I try in another way and I created a view (tables C and D). Then, now I have:

```
A (primary table; key field id_a)
B (join to A by id_a; one to one relationship)
VIEW D (FK id_a; one to many relationship)
```

I  have in design view:

detail a:

```
Name column X: value of A.column_x
Name column Y: value of A.column_y
Name column Z: value of B.column_z
```

detail b:

```
Name column D.column_j      Name column D.column_i
XYJ                          HJU
IOP                          IOP
```

But i continue having the same problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: where are you placing first part and second part in report?

Comment: why you don't change your C table link to B rather that A to avoid multiples link to same table field?

Comment: Siva: Now, I'm placing both parts in different detail sections. cojimarmiami: I removed joins in CR because now I'm using Table A, B (join between them) and a view.

Comment: @veri Could you please update your post with your new changes?

Answer (score 0):

if you place in 2 details then the output will be one that you are getting...

To get the required output...

Put these in page header

```
Name column X: value of A.column_x
Name column Y: value of A.column_y
Name column Z: value of B.column_z
```

Put these in details:

```
Name column D.column_j      Name column D.column_i
XYJ                          HJU
IOP                          IOP
```

if you have data in page header repeating then the wayout would be:

1. Create 2 sub reports in main report... one report in `details a` and one in `details b`.

In `details a` place below fields

```
 Name column X: value of A.column_x
 Name column Y: value of A.column_y
 Name column Z: value of B.column_z
```

In `details b` place below fields

```
Name column D.column_j      Name column D.column_i
XYJ                          HJU
IOP                          IOP
```